# Удалить все символы дубликаты в строке, кроме первого слева

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Каким регулярным выражением удалить символы дубликаты в строке?

Строка имеет вид `1212.547..12.21`.

Надо удалить все точки справа, оставив первую точку слева.
Чтобы получилось `1212.5471221`.

Comment: А вам именно регулярки нужны или проблему решить? Без регулярок могу подсказать, хотя это и будет не очень оптимально.

Comment: Зачем тут регулярные выражения?! `a,b = x.split('.', 2); a + '.' + ''.join(b.split('.'))`. Можно также `replace()` использовать или `map()`. НА вкус и цвет, что называется.

Comment: @simf, не нужно менять вопрос полностью, если уже есть ответы на первоначальную версию вопроса (в том числе и ваш). Так вы делаете ответы неправильными. Если возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [str.partition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
first, sep, rest = x.partition(".")
res = first + sep + rest.replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказки.

это работает

```
x = "1212.547....12.21"
b = x.split('.', -1)[0] + '.' + ''.join(x.split('.', -1)[1:])

>>1212.5471221
```